# Sonar 4.5.1 with HTML Issues Report plugin 1.0 error

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I've recently installed Sonar 4.5.1 with Sonar Runner 2.4, Issue report plugin 1.0.

It reports error when running the analysis:

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: Fail to generate HTML Issues Report to: /home/.sonar/issues-report.html
ERROR: Caused by: ruleStatus.getRule().getId() is undefined.
ERROR: 
ERROR: To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run SonarQube Runner with the -e switch.
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Build step 'Invoke Standalone Sonar Analysis' marked build as failure
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Issue report plugin 1.3 solved the problem.